# Meta-analysis effect size conversion: regression coefficient to correlation coefficient (r)

Tags: regression-coefficients, meta-analysis

I am trying to extract data from an article for a meta-analysis. I would like to convert the following information into a correlation coefficient (r):

Pre-covid period: Nov 19 2019 - March 2 2020 (104days)
Covid: March 2 2020 - May 12 2020 (71days)
Over the study period (November 19-2019 to May 12-2020; 175 days), 138,615 prescriptions for buprenorphine were issued.

A mean of 911.13 (SD = 220.66) patients filled a prescription for buprenorphine each day. The interrupted time series model demonstrated that buprenorphine prescriptions declined insignificantly at a rate of 1.8 prescriptions per day in the COVID period (B = -1.75, 95%CI = -5.8 to 2.34). In the pre-COVID period, 358.79 (SD = 66.28) prescribers issued a prescription for prevalent buprenorphine patients each weekday, in the COVID period, the number of daily prescribers declined insignificantly at a rate of 0.32 prescribers per day (B = -0.32,95%CI = -1.47 to 0.82)compared to the baseline.

Is the B regression coefficient given the unstandardized or standardized beta? and could i use the B's presented above as correlation coefficient (r) effect sizes in my meta analysis or do i have to do some conversion? if so could someone please tell me how I could do this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you need to double check the information you have as those confidence intervals are not consistent with the coefficient or the text.

Comment: I did check, and the information is correct, at least how it is presented in the article. The text is pulled from an article by Thornton et al. 2020. which you can find here https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33031213/

Comment: -1.71 does not fall between -5.8 and -2.34 and the CI does not include zero. The other one has the same problem.

Comment: So is the article reporting incorrect information? ( sent a link with the article above)

Comment: The authors have used a dash instead of the word _to_ or a comma and hence in your version it appears to be a minus sign.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for pointing that out. Fixed it, could you help me out with my question or?

Comment: I do not think there is any easy way to change $\hat\beta$ into $r$. without asking the authors it is hard to tell if they are standardised, it is all Lombard Street to a China orange that they are unstandardised in a health journal